# The projection of a force vector on cordinates, a minor confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image: Example from kleppner book]

I'm confused about the fact that If I look on one triangle, I find that in the radial direction, the projection of W is sin(a)/W, and on another triangle, which is what the book picked, the projection of W is W*sin(a) which is a form I'm indeed more used to see.
I tried to show what I mean in this little paint diagram.

[image: paint diagram]

What am I wrong about the first triangale trigonometry ?

Comment: Note also that the $W/\sin \theta$ had to be wrong because it implies a component of the weight vector was bigger than the magnitude of the weight vector itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to split $W$ into radial part and tangential part. Your fist triangle achieves exactly that, since you have one side along W, one along the tangent and one parallel to the radius.

However in your second triangle you have one side along W (good), one side along the radius (good) and **one side which has both tangential and radial components** (not good).